# All possible partitions (clusters) of Tree

Tags: python, algorithm, tree

Let's say the tree has **n** vertices and **n-1** edges. All nodes are connected. I want to divide the tree into parts, where each part must contain at least **2** vertices.

In how many possible ways I can do this?

*Example:*

```
     1
   /   \
  2     3
 / \     \
4   5     6
```

For the tree given above, answer is **3**

```
1. [1,2,3,4,5,6] 
2. [1,3,6] and [2,4,5]
3. [3,6] and [1,2,4,5]

        1                   1               1    
      /   \                  \             /   
1)   2     3      2)    2     3      3)   2     3 
    / \     \          / \     \         / \     \ 
   4   5     6        4   5     6       4   5     6
```

Comment: By "divide the tree into parts" do you mean by removing zero or more edges and making no other changes? Are there any restrictions on the code, such as efficiency, avoiding recursion, or the like? What data structure does the tree use? That last one is critical for finding efficiency or for writing code, since some structures can easily find the parent of a node and others cannot, etc. Your three partitions for your example are *not* tree structures as written, they merely can be interpreted as such given your example tree.

Comment: Perhaps I should add two more operations that depend greatly on the data structure used for the tree: splitting a tree into two identifiable trees by removing one edge, and counting the number of nodes in an identified tree. The time involved depends on the structure.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Yes I mean, remove zero or more edges. I believe it can be done O(n^2) time complexity or better. All nodes and their connections are given as list and I build tree, so no root declared. Its just any kind of tree with N node and N-1 edge. No disjoints

Comment: Why would you count `1-3-6` but not `2-4` or `2-5`?

Comment: @גלעדברקן Because each partition must contain at least 2 elements. Check answer. Edited

Comment: OK, I believe you mean that the tree is not rooted, you are given a list of 2-tuples or of sets with two elements, each list item representing an edge and tuple/set item a node, and you are assured that the list represents a connected tree, which includes that if you used 2-tuples that each tuple has distinct nodes and that if (a,b) is in the list then (b,a) is not. Thanks for that not-quite-complete statement of your data structure. My question about the acceptability of a `O(2**n)` algorithm remains.

Comment: @RoryDaulton my knowledge about graph and trees are limited, sorry for unclear definition. O(2 ** n) is too big. I need at least n**2 if its possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a linear-time DP. Let `P(u)` be the number of valid partitions of the subtree rooted at `u`. Let `A(u)` be the number of "almost valid" partitions of the subtree rooted at `u`, that is, every node but `u` belongs to a part with at least two vertices. We have the recurrence

```
P(u) = product_{v in Children(u)} (2 P(v) + A(v)) - A(u)
A(u) = product_{v in Children(u)} P(v),
```

which can be evaluated in linear time.

The intuition behind the recurrence is to do a case analysis on `u`, the root of the subtree under consideration.

1. `u` is in a part with none of its children. The partition is almost valid; all subtrees rooted at a child of `u` have valid partitions.
2. `u` is in a part with one or more of its children. The children in the same part are valid or almost valid; the children in a different part are valid. Valid children have two choices (join with their parent or not); almost valid children have one (join with their parent).

As an example, on the tree

```
     1
   /   \
  2     3
 / \     \
4   5     6
```

we have

```
A(4) = 1  (empty product is 1)
P(4) = 1 - A(4) = 0
A(5) = 1
P(5) = 1 - A(5) = 0
A(2) = P(4) P(5) = 0
P(2) = (2 P(4) + A(4)) (2 P(5) + A(5)) - A(2) = 1
A(6) = 1
P(6) = 1 - A(6) = 0
A(3) = P(6) = 0
P(3) = (2 P(6) + A(6)) - A(3) = 1
A(1) = P(2) P(3) = 1
P(1) = (2 P(2) + A(2)) (2 P(3) + A(3)) - A(1) = 3.
```

On the tree

```
   1
 /   \
2     3
       \
        6
```

we have

```
A(2) = 1
P(2) = 1 - A(2) = 0
A(6) = 1
P(6) = 1 - A(6) = 0
A(3) = P(6) = 0
P(3) = (2 P(6) + A(6)) - A(3) = 1
A(1) = P(2) P(3) = 0
P(1) = (2 P(2) + A(2)) (2 P(3) + A(3)) - A(1) = 2.
```

Comment: Could you please explain a bit your definitions? In particular, I don't understand what an *almost valid* partition is.

Comment: @Rightleg Valid means that every node in the subtree belongs to a part that contains at least one other subtree node. "Almost valid" means that every node in the subtree that is not the root of the subtree belongs to a part that contains at least one other subtree node, and the root of the subtree belongs to a part that contains no other subtree node.

Comment: I think I'm bugging on "belonging to a part"... If a tree has at least two nodes, then shouldn't every node belong to a part with at least two nodes? What's a *part* exactly?

Comment: @Rightleg I guess the question terminology is cluster, not part.

Comment: Still, how do you define a cluster? Isn't it a connected set of nodes?

Comment: @Rightleg Set of nodes connected after the cuts have been made. The counts here are the number of distinct partitions considering only the nodes in the subtree.

Comment: Thank you for the inspiration. Could you please outline how to apply your recurrence to a (simple) tree with two children where only one of the children has a single child? (As an array, `[None,1,2,3,None,None,6,None]`, like the OP's example but `2` is without children.) I can't wrap my head around how to apply the formula.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Done.

Comment: I think I finally get it. Beautiful solution!

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution.

My script is not optimized, and can take a long time to run. Besides, it makes the assumption that the tree is binary, as the example you gave in your question.

```
def count_partitions(tree):
    if len(tree.nodes()) <= 1:
        return 0
    elif len(tree.nodes()) == 2:
        return 1
    else:
        count = 1
        for edge in tree.edges():
            upper, lower = tree.cut(edge)
            count += count_partitions(upper) * count_partitions(lower)
        return count
```

So, how does it work.

As a matter of fact, if a tree has zero or one node, it cannot be partitioned in trees with each at least two nodes. If a tree has two nodes, there is exactly one such partition.

If a tree has an arbitrary number of nodes greater than 2, then there is at least one such partition (`count = 1`). So one after the other (`for edge in tree.edges`), I remove each edge from the tree (`tree.cut(edge)`). This operation of removing an edge results in two trees. The number of partitions is then equal to the product of the number of partitions of both of these sub-trees (`count_partitions(upper) * count_partitions(lower)`).

You can test it on your example; it will as expected return `3`.

About the complexity, it's not really good. I don't know if there are other ways to do this that are more efficient, but this one looks to me like a **O(card(edges)!)**: at a given state with `n` edges, for each edge, a loop over the `n-1` other edges is performed.

Here is an evaluation of the execution time on small trees created randomly:

- 5 nodes: 0.0005s
- 6 nodes: 0.0019s
- 7 nodes: 0.0057s
- 8 nodes: 0.022s
- 9 nodes: 0.096s
- 10 nodes: 0.44s
- 11 nodes: 2.144s (from here, I made my tests on fewer trees)
- 12 nodes: 11.85s

---

**Implementation details**

I wrote a `Tree` class (and a `Node`) class, which has mainly three methods: `nodes`, `edges`, and `cut`. I made this script pretty quickly, so I only tried to come up with something that works, regardless of the efficiency. There must be better ways to implement this.

The `Tree.cut` method is the most important (not that it is really complex though). It cuts a tree in two parts along an edge, and returns the two new trees.

```
def cut(self, edge):
    upper_tree = Tree(self)
    lower_tree = Tree()
    for node in upper_tree.nodes():
        if node.value == edge[0].value:
            if node.left and node.left.value == edge[1].value:
                lower_tree.root = node.left
                node.left = None
            elif node.right and node.right.value == edge[1].value:
                lower_tree.root = node.right
                node.right = None

            return (upper_tree, lower_tree)
```

---

**UPDATE**

As discussed in the comments, I tried to memoize the function.

I chose to memoize on the tree's nodes, because it was alright in my implementation. The result is of course way better than previously; here are comparative execution times:

- 5 nodes: 0.0006s
- 6 nodes: 0.0013s
- 7 nodes: 0.0021s
- 8 nodes: 0.0036s
- 9 nodes: 0.0067s
- 10 nodes: 0.012s
- 11 nodes: 0.022s
- 12 nodes: 0.040s
- 13 nodes: 0.076s
- 20 nodes: 8.07s

The same sub-tree is created many times in the process of the main function, so the memoization is very beneficial.

Here is the code of the memoization (very specific to this implementation):

```
class Memoize:
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function
        self.memory = list()

    def __call__(self, x):
        nodes = x.nodes()
        for elt in self.memory:
            if elt[0] == nodes:
                return elt[1]
        result = self.function(x)
        self.memory.append((nodes, result))
        return result

count_partitions = Memoize(count_partitions)
```

Comment: Thanks for effort. O(n!) is not good though. DP apporach can be helpful here maybe and some memorization of repetative counting

Comment: @safarov That's a sure thing, `O(n!)` is pretty bad, but this is a theoretical approach. The frequency of "dead-ends" (namely, when one of the two sub-trees has less than 2 nodes) must be taken in consideration as well, and I think it's rather high. In addition, memorization could greatly improve the performances. Maybe memorizing the lists of edges could be the right solution. I might give it a try. Anyway, the algorithm itself seems to me pretty decent, and I'm not really sure there's a better way (though I'm far from an expert).

Comment: @safarov I've tried the memoization, and updated my answer according to this. The speed results are pretty satisfying.